# How to avoid adding "async" to hundreds of locations in my code when adding a simple fetch call?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I'm working on a big project with complex code that is not well written, it looks like spaghetti, with a lot of imbrications, functions calling each other with a lot of stack depth.

Please note that as of now, **the project code is 100% synchronous** (no promises, no API calls, no database, no IO - it's a very complex test project that relies on hardcoded scenarios).

**The evolution I need to code:**

In a very deep sub-function, I need to do a very simple API call (using fetch) to return a simple integer value to the parent function, instead of an hardcoded value.

**The problem I get:**

Obviously, I need to change this function to async and I need to await for the result.

But now, in the functions calling it, I need to await for the result, which means I need to set those parent functions to async as well, but then their parents need to await and to become async... All the way to the top, which, in this project, I estimate to around 100 functions to update.

Is there a way to do this that wouldn't require refactoring so much occurences?

Comment: I think this might be a better fit for [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) since there is no direct solution to your problem.  In other words, this isn't a **coding** problem, it's a refactoring problem.  Maybe if you give a high level example of how the code currently works (how the code uses the async data) we might be able to help with a stop-gap solution.  The only answer I can think of the way your question is now is: "one line at a time with lots of unit tests".

Comment: Can you not raise the call higher, run it async, and then call the sync function flow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to do this that wouldn't require refactoring so much occurences?

Not a **good** one, no.¹ Once you've introduced asynchronousness, you have to allow for it right the way up the call chain. You can't convert an asynchronous process into a synchronous one.

If your app works in a loop as many apps do (well, at a low level all Node.js apps do in some sense, but you know what I mean), you might have one loop start the async process and store the result somewhere, then subsequent loops can check to see if it's there and, if it is, use it. But that depends on whether that will actually suit your situation.

Otherwise, you've tagged [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js), so the bad browser hack for this² doesn't apply. There appears to be [an equivalent bad Node.js hack](https://github.com/ForbesLindesay/sync-request), though: Doing the request synchronously. I **strongly** recommend **not doing that** *(at least not without really carefully thinking it through)* since it will suspend the thread you do it on, bringing all other processing on that thread (I/O completions, etc.) to a halt until the request completes. It's a very bad idea. But it's there as a last resort or part of a migration strategy.

---

¹ Or at least, not a good one that avoids having to make a different change to all of those places (adding a callback they all pass around — even worse than making everything `async`).

² `XMLHttpRequest`'s `async: false` option, which makes it synchronous, locking up the UI of the browser until the request completes. **Not** a good idea. :-)

Comment: @zero298 - I think you're right! I don't know how I missed that. I'll fix it.